# In Munchkin, can a thief steal at level 1?

Tags: munchkin

Can a thief steal at level 1 given that failing to steal causes the thief to lose a level?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [Official Munchkin FAQ](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/faq/) says **Yes.**

> Q. What happens to a Level 1 Thief who fails an attempt to steal? Does
>   he die?
>
> A. Nothing happens to him. You can't go below Level 1. (Beware
>   the Level 1 Thief – he literally has nothing to lose!)

Answer (score 12):

We have played it this way.  I've not found anything in the rules that indicates that you need to be able to cover the cost of failing before attempting the theft. Also, this is probably the best time to use the Theft ability since your level can never go below 1.